# "Undefined Mixin" in Sass compiler for bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I am using the bootstrap-sass code to create a project. I keep on getting an "undefined mixin" alert every time I tried to compile the bootstrap-sass code. Is there something wrong with the way the code is coded or are the settings / folders in compiler placed incorrectly?

```
 @mixin alert-variant($background, $border, $color) {
  color: $color;
  @include gradient-bg($background);
  border-color: $border;

  hr {
    border-top-color: darken($border, 5%);
  }

  .alert-link {
    color: darken($color, 10%);
  }
}
```

Here's the @include part:

```
    @each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .alert-#{$color} {
    @include alert-variant(theme-color-level($color, $alert-bg-level), theme-color-level($color, $alert-border-level), theme-color-level($color, $alert-color-level));
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your project structure and how are you importing Bootstrap mixins?

Comment: Make sure that the file that holds all your imports has all of your mixins defined before you're calling them. Also, some editors don't like it when you dont explicitly define mixins or custom variables from within the working file.

Comment: So I am currently using main.scss with folders (mixins, partials, utilities, vendor) - compiling it with the sass compiler called prepos. It bumps back with "undefined mixins" or how would I explicitly define the mixins more?